# How can I refresh the page dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Refresh a PHP page for every predefined seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815003/refresh-a-php-page-for-every-predefined-seconds)

I have some code and would like to refresh the page every 20 seconds.

The refresh has to be on the events. I mean, if I load the web, and then someone puts  something on the table, I would like to display that every 20 secs (for example).

This is the link: http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2012/07/twitter-style-dynamic-tweet-update.html

Comment: Lookup javascript's setInterval function

Comment: Be sure to distinguish refreshing the *page* (can be done with meta refresh tag, or setting `window.location` inside a `setTimeout`), and refreshing its *content* (which requires AJAX, and is pretty well explained on the linked page).

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript's `setInterval()` (more specifically, `window.setInterval()`) to run functions at an interval. something like this:

```
setInterval(myFunction,20000); //time is in milliseconds, so 20 seconds is 20000

function myFunction() {
  console.log('hi');
  //or whatever else you want to run at an interval.
}
```

Comment: But I don't have any function. How can I do it? Where do I put that?

Comment: that's your job to create the function and apply it since you didn't show any thing of what you have.

Comment: yes, all the code is on the website ken
http://tuts.wtfdiary.com/2012/07/twitter-style-dynamic-tweet-update.html

Answer (score 0):

Create PHP Get data and JavaScript function that will implement GET

```
//Ajax call to get tweets

function GetTweets(){
    $.ajax({
    url: "Get_tweet.php",
    data: /supply parameter if you have any/,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
       $("#content").prepend(html);
    }
    });
}
```

use window.setInterval method to call the function and to get the data based on your specified interval

```
window.setInterval(GetTweets(),20000)
```

Comment: I now have this:
function GetTweets(){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post_tweet.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
    $("#tweet").val('');
    $(html).prependTo("#content").fadeIn(500);
    }
    });
   }
   }return false;
   }); });
   window.setInterval(GetTweets(),20000)
It doesn't work, what went wrong?

Comment: as I said you should create GET. What you have is just a POST which is only use for posting. Create counterpart of it which is GET to get the data